# Track Scanner activity on Mobile phone

Tags: android, ios, mobile, barcode-scanner

We send coupons to our customers and they view it using our mobile app. We have implemented  options to track customer clicks.But we don't know whether they used it or not in the store. We don't have any option to track using our POS (Point of Sale) devices. POS devices doesn't track coupons, but it just validates. Making POS devices software change is out of scope at this point of time due to timelines. Is it possible to implemented something on mobile app which will track whether the barcode is scanned by a scanner or not?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using analytics you can know whether a user accessed the coupon screen, but it is just an image shown on the screen, of which, the scanner essentially takes a photo. If the user consents to sharing their location you could try and correlate accessing the coupon with your store locations

Comment: @Paulw11 thank you. As i mentioned, user may view the coupon but they wouldn't used it in store. So analytics page wouldn't help us.

Comment: Unless you can issue unique coupon codes to customers and get the POS system to track those codes then there is no way to know if a particular customer used their coupon.